# Extraction of directory and page bits off a linear address

Tags: c, x86, bit-shift

As many sources say that using `((1 << x) -1) << y` isolates `x` bits
starting from `y` to `y + x`, and a linear address is built like this: `0:11` is the offset, `12:21` is the page and `22:31`is the directory.
However, when I use the bit mask above and try to extract the directory for example, it doesn't seem to work at all.

```c
/* unsigned address */
#define MASK_DIR    ((1u << 9) - 1) << 22

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int dir;
    uint32_t addr = 0x12345678;

    dir = MASK_DIR & addr;
    printf("%#x", dir); // 0x12000000
}
```

Extracting the *offset* works well when using `(1u << 11) - 1` with the same process as above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. General hint: You should enclose the replacement content for your macros in `( )` to avoid funny issues with operator precedence. For debugging you should also print (or inspect in debugger) what mask value is created by your macro.

Comment: What output did you expect and why? If you clear the lower 22 bits, you get what you see in your output. Do you expect to see `0x48`?

Comment: @Gerhardh Well I actually get the correct the value, my bad. But look at the page mask `(((1u << 9) - 1) << 12)` I get `0x145000`.

Comment: Again: What did you expect? Did you verify what mask is created? Do you expect `0x345000`? Are you aware, that bits `12:21` are 10 bits? Also `0:11` are 12 bits.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output you get and what you expect. Add what you think works well (also with result) and what does not.

Comment: Your PAGE_MASK is 0x1FF000.  That & 0x12345678 is `0x145000`, keeping the two hex digits that line up with the FF part, and turning the `3` into a `1`, keeping its low bit.  As @Gerhardh says, this is too few bits in your mask; each level of the page table should be 10.  (10 + 10 + 12(page-shift) = 32).  But 1FF only has 9 set bits.  Seems like a mixup between inclusive vs. exclusive ranges, i.e. an off-by-one in the `x` in your formula.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, there's also the common mistake of not wrapping macros in parenthesis. Write something like `MASK_DIR + 1` and you'll get very strange bugs.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you! I knew it could cause some bugs and I forgot to use `()`, thank you for the mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gerhardh corrected my false calculation in which I thought `0-11` is *11* bits even though it's *12*. With that said I was able to isolate all the required bits from the 32-bit address, with the following macros

```c
#define ADDR_PAGE(addr)   ((((1u << 10) - 1) << 12) & addr)
#define ADDR_DIR(addr)    ((((1u << 10) - 1) << 22) & addr)
#define ADDR_OFF(addr)    (((1u << 12) - 1) & addr)
```

Output
`0x678 - 0x345000 - 0x12000000 (offset, page, dir)`

Comment: Really? After all the comments you still don't have `( )` around that expression? And you should also put some around `addr`.

Comment: You must also enclose `addr` : `& (addr)`

Comment: Consider what happens with `ADDR_OFF( x ? a : b )`.  That expands to `( (stuff) & x ? a : b)`.  That's why you always wrap macro args with () when expanding them inside the macro, except cases like `abs(addr)`.  Even `printf("%d", addr)` could maybe break if the macro arg used the comma operator.  (`x, y` evaluates side effects in both, and produces `y` as the value).